# Looking for concise alternative for RandomStringUtils

Tags: java, apache-commons

> This question is obsolete. `org.apache.commons:commmons-lang3:3.7` removed the deprecated flag, and 3.8 confirmed that.

After updating to `org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6` from `3.5` I get many warnings about `RandomStringUtils` being deprecated. The suggested alternative is `RandomStringGenerator` from `commons-text`. However, that class is very clumsy to use if all you want is just a string (say, in a unit test). Compare:

```
String name1 = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(FIRST_NAME_LENGTH);
String name2 = new RandomStringGenerator.Builder().withinRange('a', 'z').build()
        .generate(FIRST_NAME_LENGTH);
```

(I know that that’s not even the same semantics, but wanted to keep it short.)

So I’m looking for a short and elegant way, ideally a drop-in replacement; Java 8, Spring, Guava and even test-only libraries are all welcome.

Comment: How about just building a wrapper around the `RandomStringGenerator`

Comment: what all functionalities you are looking for?

Comment: @redflar3: Mostly I need short strings of digits or short strings of ‘usual’ alphanumerical characters. They usually stand for values entered by the users in forms.

Comment: since version 3.7 deprecation of RandomStringUtils is removed ;-)
see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-1346 or release notes for reasons

Comment: Good! This obsoletes my question. No button for that. I will delete the question once version 3.6 really phases out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would consider using the [Facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) to wrap the "clumsiness" of the `RandomStringGenerator` class.

**Example**:

```
public class RandomStringUtilsFacade
{
    public static String randomAlphabetic (final int firstNameLength)
    {
        return randomAlphabetic(firstNameLength, 'a', 'z');
    }

    // If you want to use the range
    public static String randomAlphabetic (final int firstNameLength, 
                                           final char low, final char high)
    {
        return new RandomStringGenerator.Builder().withinRange(low, high).build()
        .generate(firstNameLength);
    }
}
```

Comment: That’s one easy (and good) solution, of course, but I would really have preferred a one-liner. I don’t quite understand why it got deprecated in the first place.

Comment: @MichaelPiefel Unless I'm misinterpreting your comment, It is one-liner: `String name1 = RandomStringUtilsFacade.randomAlphabetic(FIRST_NAME_LENGTH);`

Comment: Of course it’s a one-liner after adding a 15-line façade. :-)

I guess I’ll end up doing something very much along these lines. Gives me the opportunity to add specialised forename generators.

Comment: @MichaelPiefel Fair enough - holistically it's not a one-liner. Well, good luck with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
return org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.random(24, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789");
```

how about this str @Michael Markidis

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks